# What is the concentration of H2 for the equation H2+I2=2HI if the equilibrium constant is 64 and the initial concentrations are both 1.9

Tags: equilibrium, concentration

So for this, I set up the equation =

$$64= \frac{(x)^2}{(1.9-x)^2}$$

I took the sqrt of both sides and got

$$8=\frac{x}{(1.9-x)}$$

So then I did $$8(1.9-x)=x$$

And simplified I got $$15.2=9x$$

So $$x=1.688$$

So to find concentration it’s Initial- Change

$$1.9-1.688=.212$$

But it’s telling me this answer is wrong

Comment: $x$ moles of reactant consumed will yield $2x$ moles of product, so the first equation needs to be modified.

Comment: So you get 0.212 sausages per square meter, or what is your unit?

Answer (score 2):

- let the amount of $\ce{H2}$ reacted = $\pu{x~mol}$
- Use the molar ratio to detemine the amount of $\ce{I2}$ reacted and the amount of $\ce{HI}$ formed:
  $$\begin{align}
  &\text{The amount of }\ce{H2}~\text{reacts to reach equilibrium }&=\pu{x~mol}\\
  &\text{The amount of }\ce{I2}~\text{reacts to reach equilibrium}&=\pu{x~mol}\\
  &\text{The amount of }\ce{HI}~\text{formed at equilibrium }&=\pu{2x~mol}\\
  \end{align}$$
- Use the following table to determine the amount and the concentration 
  of each species at equilibrium : 
  $$\begin{align}
  \ce{&H2 &&+ &&O2 &<=> &&2HI\\
  I~~~~  &1.9   &&&&1.9      &&&0 \\
  C ~~~  &-x    &&&&-x       &&&2x \\
  E ~~~  &(1.9-x) &&&&(1.9-x) &&&2x} 
  \end{align}$$
- Th concentrations at equilibrium :
  $$[\ce{H2}]_\mathrm{e}=(1.9-x)  , [\ce{I2}]_\mathrm{e}=(1.9-x) ,  [\ce{HI}]_\mathrm{e}= \pu{2x~M} $$
- Sustitute the concentrations in the following formula:
  $$\begin{align}
  K_\mathrm{C} = \frac{ [\ce{HI}]_\mathrm{e}   }  {[\ce{H2}]_\mathrm{e}[\ce{I2}]_\mathrm{e} }\\
  64= \frac{(2x)^2}{(1.9-x)(1.9-x)}
  \end{align}$$
- Take the square root of both sides :
  $$\sqrt{64}=\sqrt{\frac{(2x)^2}{(1.9-x)^2}}$$

$$8=\frac{2x}{(1.9-x)}$$
- Solve for $x : x=1.52$

- Calculate the concentrations at equilibrium :
  $$\begin{align}
  [\ce{H2}]_\mathrm{e}&=(1.9-x)&=(1.9-1.52)&=\pu{0.38~M}  \\
  [\ce{I2}]_\mathrm{e}&=(1.9-x)&= (1.9-1.52)&=\pu{0.38~M} \\ 
   [\ce{HI}]_\mathrm{e}&= \pu{2\times{x}}&= 2\times{1.52}&=\pu{3.04~M}
  \end{align} $$

Comment: Why is it 2X^2, instead of just X^2

Comment: When $\pu{x~mol}$ of $\ce{H2}$ reacted ,$\pu{ 2x ~mol}$ of $\ce{HI}$ formed ,so $[\ce{HI}]_\mathrm{e}=\pu{2x~M}$ and $[\ce{HI}]^2_\mathrm{e}=(2x)^2$ .